# How many $n$-qubit states are entangled?

Tags: entanglement

My question is a bit broad, but my concern is mainly on understand the ratio between the number of possible linear combinations that can be decomposed in a direct product of states and the number of possible entangled states in that system. The system is a just an $n$-qubits set, as an usual vector space, with the assumption that all the states in a certain superposition can be expected as equally probable. As an example to clarify what I mean take:

$$
\left| \psi \right\rangle = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} (\left| 00 \right\rangle + \left| 11 \right\rangle)
$$

I know that the ratio in a 2-qubits system should be 50%, but what about $n=100$?

To improve the clarity of the question I would ask, how do you interpret this kind of graph?[image: Product = a state that can be decomposed uniquely by a tensorr product. Entangled = it's own defition.]

Where Product = a state that can be decomposed uniquely by a tensor product. Entangled = it's own defition.
Is this a true picture of what's going on in an $n$-qubit system or not?

Comment: As far as I am aware you can not import the physics package (which includes the bra-ket commands) (or any other package, for that matter). However, the commands \rangle and \langle will work as a substitute.

Comment: [Here's the tutorial](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/50/15).

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking what is the probability of finding an entangled state when sampling random pure $n$-qubit pure states? Or the probability of finding an entangled state when sampling among the $n$-qubit pure *balanced* states? Or something else?

Comment: Thanks JSdJ for your help.

Comment: glS: I would rather say about sampling a random pure $n$-qubit system, not a mixed one. What do you mean by balanced sorry?

Comment: I mean a state like the one you put in your post. I don't understand where that state comes from if you are sampling random states (also, note that I won't get a notification, and thus probably not see your answer, if you don't tag me with @glS)

Comment: @glS that state was just one random state that you can write in $n$=2 but look at the graph that I added to understand what I mean. Thank you.

Comment: then the answer should be that the probability is $1$: almost all states are entangled. See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/268853/58382). See also [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.65.064304)

Comment: @glS I think we have a winner. It's very theoretical but understandable. Thank you. Create an answer if you want.

Comment: @Kamui9610 *"I know that the ratio in a 2-qubits system should be 50%,"* --- Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of finding an entangled state while randomly sampling (from the uniform distribution) over pure states is one: almost all pure states are entangled.

This is shown in [this answer on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/268853/58382). [This paper](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.65.064304) might also be of interest.

The gist is that separable states correspond to rank-1 matrices, which have zero measure in the set of all matrices. This is also discussed in [this post on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1872332/173147).

Another less rigorous argument could be to observe that separable states are always infinitesimally close to entangled out: given an arbitrary separable pure state $|\Psi\rangle\equiv|\psi\rangle\otimes|\phi\rangle$, take $|u\rangle,|v\rangle$ such that $\langle u|\psi\rangle=\langle v|\phi\rangle=0$. Then, the state
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2}}\left[|\Psi\rangle+\epsilon(|u\rangle\otimes|v\rangle)\right]$$
is entangled for all $\epsilon>0$ and can be made to be infinitesimally close to $|\Psi\rangle$. This hints towards the set of separable states having empty interior (although technically, having empty interior is not in itself enough to prove having zero measure, see e.g. [this blog post](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/08/the_difference_between_measure.html)).